# Merge array of objects into one object - objects have same name attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I merge this data?

I have an array of 2 objects containing other nested objects.

It looks like:

[image]

I need the values from both geometry and properties to be in a single object instead of 2.

I have tried:

```js
// first method:
console.log(arrObj.reduce(((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c)), {}));

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...arrObj));

// second method

const tltVehicles = gpsData.map((vehicle) => vehicle.geometry.coordinates);

const points = tltVehicles.map(([lng, lat]) => ({
    longitude: lng,
    latitude: lat,
  }));

const vehiclesProperties = gpsData.map((vehicle) => vehicle.properties);

const vehiclesData = Object.assign(points, vehiclesProperties);
```

None of these appear to work.

Ideally, I would want the data displayed something like this:

```
[
  {
  direction:   64,
  id:          3897,
  line:        63,
  type:        2,
  coordinates: [24.82993, 59.44876],
  }
]
```

Any suggestions?

So, someone had my question closed and referred to a similar question. However, I have tried those methods and illustrated those here. The problem as I've already stated is this doesn't work if objects have the same name attributes, the second object ends up overwriting the first one.

What else can I try?

Comment: write the input JSON instead of image

Comment: Please post object structure, code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [already been closed anyway...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64076403/1541563)

Comment: Something like this : with help of spread operator: `{...result.properties, ...result.geometry}`can bring you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The previous question was closed incorrectly as it was actually different to others due to the same item names in the objects.

The spread operator doesn't work, as I already mentioned.

I put an Image because in my previous post I was scolded for putting the code from the JSON response and I was asked for an image.

Turns out the solution can be done with lodaash as it does a deep merge, whereas the traditional JS only does a shallow merge.

```js
  const tltVehicles = gpsData.map((vehicle) => vehicle.geometry.coordinates);
  const points = tltVehicles.map(([lng, lat]) => ({
    longitude: lng,
    latitude: lat,
  }));
  const vehiclesProperties = gpsData.map((vehicle) => vehicle.properties);
  const vehiclesData = _.merge(points, vehiclesProperties);

  console.log('result', vehiclesData);
```